# Function runtime fails to start with "claim is empty" error on service bus trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I set up a couple of topics to work with a new function app for a system currently in development, and every time it tries to start I get a failure error.

> The function runtime is unable to start. Please check the 
>       runtime logs for any errors or try again later. 
>       Microsoft.ServiceBus: The remote server returned an error: 
>       (401) Unauthorized. claim is empty. TrackingId:b221222c-
>       df39-4abb-8af7-8afd880fd363_G8, SystemTracker:giftie-
>       production.servicebus.windows.net:out-smtp, 
>       Timestamp:1/19/2018 1:52:12 AM. System: The remote 
>       server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>       Session Id: 547e23d54eca44fcb2503bf88d8cb05e
>       Timestamp: 2018-01-19T01:52:31.245Z

I've checked all my shared access policies, this is happening on every subscription on both topics. I have a separate functions app which runs from a different topic, which seems to work OK.
I've tried deleting and recreating the access policies (and updating the connection strings in the AppSettings) and deleting and recreating the subscriptions.

The `function.json` looks OK, I think - here's a sample one:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "connection": "SB-out-smtp-listener",
      "topicName": "out-smtp",
      "subscriptionName": "smtp-sendgrid",
      "access": "manage",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "jsonMessage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\notifications.hellogiftie.com.dll",
  "entryPoint": "notifications.hellogiftie.com.ApiServiceBus.SbSmtpSendgrid.Run"
}
```

I'm very confused at this point and would be grateful for any ideas!

Comment: 2 questions. 1. Are you able to repro this error in some quick console app using almost the same code as your function app? 2. Does your shared access policy  have the "Send" permission? (I've used eventhubs, assuming servicebus topics work similarly with a Send/Receive policy)

Comment: The problem is that it's an incoming trigger so it's function app specific. My other function app with an SB trigger appears to work, and I can't see any differences between how they are set up. In addition, I've tried testing with the Root SA Key to ensure that there are no permissions issues, and I get the same error every time.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you try the following to isolate the cause of the issue
1. create a new SB triggered function in the same function app. The function should be triggered by the same SB that you are currently using.
2. Send a message to the SB. If your function is triggered. Good. If not you might want to test with some other SB
3. If your new function is working fine, use the KUDU console/portal to copy DLLs/code from the old function to the new one

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by completely regenerating my functions app project, and putting everything back in it, deleting the functions app on Azure, and republishing.
Even then, there was a mismatch between what I put in the ServiceBusTrigger attribute, and what was shown on the Integrate screen (although the function.json looked correct).
I had Listen rights in the attribute, but an error about Manage rights came up. The Integrate screen said I was asking for Manage rights, and after correcting this, everything started to work.

I think maybe there's something interesting about the ServiceBusTrigger attribute:

```
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("out-smtp", "smtp-sendgrid", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "SB-out-smtp-listener")]string jsonMessage, TraceWriter log)
```

Intellisense seems to tell me that there is a function signature option that has 2 access rights parameters, but describes one as "The access rights the client has to the subscription in the topic" and the other as "Gets the access rights the client as to the queue or topic subscription".

Comment: In my case this error was caused by ";" at the end of connection string. I know, it looks silly but when I removed trailing semicolon from it it started to work.

Comment: That's what fixed my issue.  Semicolons are required as separators between connection string fields, so it seems natural to have one at the end (even though not required of course), but it appears the access key allows special characters, so that's a trap. Apparently the semicolon was treated as part of the access key.  Bad configuration design.

Answer (score 0):

By default, access rights are set to "Manage" on the ServiceBusTrigger attribute. [Here's](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/v1.x/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/ServiceBusAttribute.cs) the source code if you want to dig in a little further!